# Failing to generate keys in Thunderbird Enigmail

Tags: 18.04, permissions, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP 15. Trying to encrypt my email with Enigmail in Thunderbird, but key generation fails, unfortunately. Debugging log shows the following errors:

```
2019-02-26 11:09:17.986 [DEBUG] keyRing.jsm: generateKey: subprocess = [object Object]
2019-02-26 11:09:17.986 enigmailKeygen.js: Start: gKeygenRequest = [object Object]
2019-02-26 11:09:18.019 [DEBUG] enigmailKeygen.js: onDataAvailable() gpg: Generating key
gpg: failed to start agent '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': No such file or directory
gpg: can't connect to the agent: No such file or directory
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No agent running
gpg: key generation failed: No agent running
[GNUPG:] ERROR key_generate 33554509
[GNUPG:] KEY_NOT_CREATED 
gpg: done
```

Even though the GPG agent seems to be running fine:

[image: Checking the GPG-agent.]

It may be that Enigmail is unable to access the agent due to permissions? I tried:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 .gnupg/ -R
```

and

```
$ chmod u+w .gnupg
```

and

```
$ chmod 0700 ~/.gnupg
```

as those were suggested in other threads, but to no avail. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same or at least a similar problem on **Ubuntu 18.04.**

I installed **Thunderbird** via software application, and then added **enigmail** within Thunderbird's add-ons.

Tried to generate a gnupg keypair, but failed. A look into the logfile

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

showed permission / access problems with **[apparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor)**, like:

```
**apparmor="DENIED"** operation="connect" profile="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" name="/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent" pid=6239 comm="gpg" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr"
```

I only then learned that Thunderbird was installed as a container-like **[snap app](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-do-not-use-snap-into-ubuntu-its-too-early/11206)**, and thus is supervised (and detained) by **apparmor**.

To check if this applies to you:

```
snap list | grep thunderbird
```

If you see Thunderbird installed as a snap app, you might like to remove and re-install it in order to get apparmor settings which will no longer interfere with normal Thunderbird/Enigmail operations.

**CAUTION**: a snap app will put all app files in your home directory, beneath the "snap" folder (NOT .snap). The removal of a snap app will delete most content of this folder, and your mail and calendar etc. data would be lost. To avoid this backup the whole thunderbird folder, to be able to copy the data back after an eventual re-install.

To remove Thunderbird as a snap app, do:

```
sudo snap remove thunderbird
```

To install it anew do the common

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
sudo apt-get install enigmail
```

Copy back your backup'ed data / folders. Recommendation: keep Thunderbird closed. Go into your new folder /home/{user}/.thunderbird and rename

```
xxxxxxx.default-release
```

into something like

```
xxxxxxx.default-release.OLD
```

copy your backup'ed default-release profile folder into this place and rename it to whatever xxxxxx.default-release originally was.

Adapt the **profiles.ini** file to reflect the xxxxxx - folder.

Start Thunderbird, create your **gnupg keypair** and have fun with it.